# Hierarchical types and page size problem in heavy sites

Tags: hierarchical

Situation:
   WP 3.3.1
   Hierarchical custom post type
   7000 posts
   Admin area

Problem:
   Pages load time > 30s

Reason:
   Page size > 1MB due to parent dropbox size in 'Quick Edit' when listing posts (appears twice) and 'Attributes' widget when editing post (just once)

Are hierarchical types unusable for large sites? Any workaround to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: How many posts per page do you have shown in the 'Screen Options'?

Comment: 20 posts per page

Answer (score 0):

Try turning down the posts per page in screen options. The posts per page actually sets the number of PARENT posts to get, so it will get those posts and their ENTIRE tree. If you turn this down, say to around 5, you should significantly cut the size of the page, since it will decrease the instances of the parent dropdown.

Comment: I've found a better description of my problem http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15459

Comment: So, I take it my solution didn't work then?